# jquery fancybox 1.3.0 iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am have some difficulty getting an iframe to load in an overlay. My user level is competent html 5 css3 xhtml and can read php and JavaScript.
I was able to get youtube video to play in lightbox_frame and iframe. but had no joy with getting an html page into an iframe in an overlay.
I was reading on fancyapps and what the example was is:
Iframe

### so adapted below.

```
<div class="portfolio3_shadow">
 <a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="page_slideshow">
<img src="../images/slideshow.png" alt=""  width="210" height="131"/></a>

<img src="../images/icon_zoom.png" style="margin-top:-30px;margin-left:86px;z-index:9999" alt=""/></div>
<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="page_slideshow" style="width:840px;height:600px">   
<iframe width="840" height="600" src="slideshow.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: It would be also very useful if you show your custom fancybox script. BTW you said you were reading fancyapps but that is for version 2.x and it's not compatible with version 1.3.x

Answer (score 2):

Rather than defining an iframe, you can mention type: iframe to get the contents as iframe in fancybox.

```
<a href="slideshow.html" id="popup">Open page</a>
```

and in script you can mention:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#popup').fancybox({
        'zoomSpeedIn': 300,
        'zoomSpeedOut': 300,
        'overlayShow': false,
        'autoScale': false,
        'type': 'iframe',
        'centerOnScroll':true
      });
  });
</script>
```

This will show the contents of the page as iframe in overlay.